# Efficiently performing operations on Erlang Tuples

Tags: erlang, tuples

Say we wish to calculate the difference between two time-stamp:

```
66> T0=now().
{1387,611376,335905}
67> T1=now().
{1387,611383,156575}
68> T1-T0.
** exception error: an error occurred when evaluating an arithmetic expression
     in operator  -/2
        called as {1387,611383,156575} - {1387,611376,335905}
69> {A1,A2,A3}=T0.
{1387,611376,335905}
70> {B1,B2,B3}=T1.
{1387,611383,156575}
71> Diff=(B1-A1)*1000000000000+(B2-A2)*1000000+(B3-A3).
6820670
72>
```

IS there a more efficient (elegant) way to do this than subtracting each corresponding element?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not more efficient way. See principally same way implemented [`timer:now_diff/2`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/timer.erl#L198) in `stdlib`:

```
%%
%% Calculate the time difference (in microseconds) of two
%% erlang:now() timestamps, T2-T1.
%%
-spec now_diff(T2, T1) -> Tdiff when
      T1 :: erlang:timestamp(),
      T2 :: erlang:timestamp(),
      Tdiff :: integer().
now_diff({A2, B2, C2}, {A1, B1, C1}) ->
    ((A2-A1)*1000000 + B2-B1)*1000000 + C2-C1.
```

Comment: That's a shame, especially since it would be helpful in many cases.

Comment: @CharlesO: I don't understand, it produces pretty efficient resulting byte code.

Comment: Very efficient byte code yes... but not as pretty as simply writing T2-T1 especially when T1 and T2 are exactly the same structure and the operator (+ or -) can be applied to each corresponding element.

Comment: It is principally `list_to_tuple([ A-B || {A, B} <- lists:zip([tuple_to_list(X) || X <- [T1, T2]])])` which is barely better.

Comment: It would be helpful if Erlang could infer simple cases like T2-T1. But you make a good point with your list comprehension example. Maybe we need some simple "Tuple Comprehension" ;)

Comment: In general case there is no operation like tuple subtraction. It always depends on semantics of the tuple elements. What result would you like in case of {1,2,3}-{3,2,1}? And what if an element is not a number?

Comment: @DmitryBelyaev {1,2,3}-{3,2,1} ={-2,0,2} and that's just fine! My point is if Erlang can infer that T1 & T2 are exactly the same structure and the operation, in this case "-" is legal on each element, then T2-T1 should be legal and your time:diff/2 function reduces to T2 - T1 ... and all similar cases with tuples consisting of the same element also benefit. T2-T1 is much easier to write and understand, when T1 and T2 are the same structure and the operator in this case "-" is legal on all elements.

Comment: You don't know T1 & T2 are exactly the same structure in compile time. It would not be efficient do it in run-time but more importantly, subtracting tuples may be error as well. It would be pretty dangerous make this over-smart run-time. You can use Perl if you would like this sort of smartness. I have written hundreds of thousands lines in Perl professionally and only thing I can say, no more. Erlang is dynamically but strongly typed language and it is good for reliability, safety and security.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need comparison:

```
1> {1387,611383,156575} > {1387,611376,335905}.
true
```